# How to read the Value for an EnumMember attribute

Tags: c#, attributes

```
public enum Status
    {

        Pending,
        [EnumMember(Value = "In Progress")]
        InProgress,
        Failed,
        Success
    }

string dbValue = "In Progress";
if (dbValue == ValueOf(Status.InProgress)){
//do some thing
}
```

How do I read the Value of Status.InProgress so I get back "in Progress"?

Answer (score 41):

This is an extension method that works with C# 8 and nullable reference types:

```cs
public static string? GetEnumMemberValue<T>(this T value)
    where T : Enum
{
    return typeof(T)
        .GetTypeInfo()
        .DeclaredMembers
        .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == value.ToString())
        ?.GetCustomAttribute<EnumMemberAttribute>(false)
        ?.Value;
}
```

Original Answer:

I've adapted this for .NET Core. Here it is:

```
public static String GetEnumMemberValue<T>(T value)
    where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    return typeof(T)
        .GetTypeInfo()
        .DeclaredMembers
        .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == value.ToString())
        ?.GetCustomAttribute<EnumMemberAttribute>(false)
        ?.Value;
}
```

Comment: `.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == value.ToString())` <-- Methinks that can be significantly optimized...

Answer (score 27):

Something like this:

```
public string GetEnumMemberAttrValue(Type enumType, object enumVal)
{
      var memInfo = enumType.GetMember(enumVal.ToString());
      var attr = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<EnumMemberAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
      if(attr != null)
      {
          return attr.Value;
      }

      return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
var enumType = typeof(Status);
var enumVal = Status.InProgress;
var str = GetEnumMemberAttrValue(enumType,enumVal);
```

Answer (score 17):

Borrowing from Amir's answer, a slightly nicer version is possible using generics as follows:

```
public string GetEnumMemberAttrValue<T>(T enumVal)
{
    var enumType = typeof(T);
    var memInfo = enumType.GetMember(enumVal.ToString());
    var attr = memInfo.FirstOrDefault()?.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<EnumMemberAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (attr != null)
    {
        return attr.Value;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Usage as follows:

```
var enumVal = Status.InProgress;
var str = GetEnumMemberAttrValue(enumVal);
```

As far as I'm aware T can't be constrained to enum's using a where clause. I would be happy to be corrected though.

Comment: You can as of c# 7.3: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-3#enhanced-generic-constraints

Answer (score 15):

Wrapped it in an extension to make it feel more natural:

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static string ToEnumMemberAttrValue(this Enum @enum)
    {
        var attr = 
            @enum.GetType().GetMember(@enum.ToString()).FirstOrDefault()?.
                GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<EnumMemberAttribute>().
                FirstOrDefault();
        if (attr == null)
            return @enum.ToString();
        return attr.Value;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
string dbValue = "In Progress";
if (dbValue == Status.ToEnumMemberAttrValue())){
    //do some thing
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you have Newtonsoft in your project, that is what you should do:

to the Enum, you should add the attribute [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]

and now you can call the JsonConvertor to serialize your value as the member string value.

in your example, it should be like that

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum Status
{

    Pending,
    [EnumMember(Value = "In Progress")]
    InProgress,
    Failed,
    Success
}

string dbValue = "In Progress";
if (dbValue == JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Status.InProgress)){
//do some thing
}
```

Note as mentioned by @Dinesh in the comment that the string is JSON therefor return with quatos so you can workaround that to get a clean string with strin.Replace method as:

```
dbValue == JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Status.InProgress).Replace("\"","");
```

Comment: The JsonConvert SerializeObject returned the enum string with double quotes, do you have any solution for this issue?

Comment: @DineshPhalwadiya yes, you are right. actualy I used it with string.Replace method like so: JsonConvert.SerializeObject(whatever).Replace("\"","")

Comment: Thanks for the response @dubi , I used StringEnumConverter & EnumMember to work it for me

Answer (score 4):

A problem with all of the approaches post so far is that they use `GetCustomAttribute<EnumMemberAttribute>` for every lookup, which is somewhat expensive.

Given that attributes loaded from reflection are immutable it makes sense to cache the `GetCustomAttribute<>` result in-memory for each enum type (`TEnum`) being looked-up.

A `static class<T>` that's generic over `T` with a static initializer effectively acts as a singleton *for every `T`*, which can be used to own an `ImmutableDictionary` to efficiently *and lazily* cache the enum member attribute data:

Because the code below is generic over `TEnum : struct, Enum` it means there is also no boxing of enum values *and* it supports enums of varying underlying-type (e.g. `enum Foo : int`, `enum Bar : long`, etc):

```cs
public static class EnumMemberNames
{
    public static String? GetNameOrNull<TEnum>( TEnum value )
        where TEnum : struct, Enum
    {
        return EnumAttribCache<TEnum>.cachedNames.TryGetValue( value, out String? text ) ? text : null;
    }

    public static String GetName<TEnum>( TEnum value )
        where TEnum : struct, Enum
    {
        return GetNameOrNull( value ) ?? value.ToString();
    }

    private static class EnumAttribCache<TEnum>
        where TEnum : struct, Enum
    {
        public static readonly ImmutableDictionary<TEnum,String> cachedNames = LoadNames();

        private static ImmutableDictionary<TEnum,String> LoadNames()
        {
            return typeof(TEnum)
                .GetTypeInfo()
                .DeclaredFields
                .Where( f => f.IsStatic && f.IsPublic && f.FieldType == typeof(TEnum) )
                .Select( f => ( field: f, attrib: f.GetCustomAttribute<EnumMemberAttribute>() ) )
                .Where( t => ( t.attrib?.IsValueSetExplicitly ?? false ) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty( t.attrib.Value ) )
                .ToDictionary(
                    keySelector    : t => (TEnum)t.field.GetValue( obj: null )!,
                    elementSelector: t => t.attrib!.Value!
                )
                .ToImmutableDictionary();
        }
    }
}
```

Used like so:

```cs
enum Foo
{
    [EnumMemberAttribute( Value = "first" )]
    A = 1,

    [EnumMemberAttribute( Value = "second" )]
    B = 2,

    Unnamed = 4
}

public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine( EnumMemberNames.GetNameOrNull( Foo.A ) ); // "first"
    Console.WriteLine( EnumMemberNames.GetNameOrNull( Foo.B ) ); // "second"
    Console.WriteLine( EnumMemberNames.GetName( Foo.Unnamed ) ); // "Unnamed"
}
```

Comment: If I use the above code I receive a compile error "The type 'TEnum' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'TEnum'  on GetNameOrNull method.

Comment: @Jafin What line gives you that error?

Comment: the public static String? GetNameOrNull.  If I add a `where TEnum : struct, Enum` then it resolves the error for me.

Comment: @Jafin Ah, thank you - I'll correct my answer now.

Answer (score 3):

```
    public static object GetMemberAttr(this Enum enumItem)
    {
        var memInfo = enumItem.GetType().GetMember(enumItem.ToString());
        var attr = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(false);
        return attr == null || attr.Length == 0 ? null :((System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute) attr[0]).Value;
    }
```

Usage:  {YouEnum}.{EnumItem}.GetMemberAttr()
 public enum TEST_ENUM
    {
        [EnumMember(Value = "1min")]
        Minute,
        [EnumMember(Value = "2min")]
        TwoMinutes,
        [EnumMember(Value = "3min")]
        ThreeMinutes,
    }

public TEST_ENUM t;

? t.TwoMinutes.GetMemberAttr()
2min

Answer (score 1):

Try This ,

```
var type = typeof(YourEnum);
var Info = type.GetMember(YourEnum.attribute); // pass enum item here
string enumdescription = Info[0].CustomAttributes.SingleOrDefault().NamedArguments[0].TypedValue.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

`[EnumMember]` attribute is used by a serializer such as Newtonsoft.

`System.Runtime.Serialization` (namespace)

`EnumMemberAttribute` (class)

*Enum:*

```
public enum Status
{
    Pending,
    [EnumMember(Value = "In Progress")]
    InProgress,
    Failed,
    Success
}
```

*Example code:*

```
string databaseValue = "In Progress";

// Serialize the enum value
string statusValue = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Status.InProgress);

if  (statusValue.Contains(databaseValue))
{
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a simple extension method.

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string ToEnumMememberAttributeValue(this Enum value)
    {
       var enumType = value.GetType();
       var enumMemeberAttribute = enumType
        .GetTypeInfo()
        .DeclaredMembers
        .Single(x => x.Name == value.ToString())
        .GetCustomAttribute<EnumMemberAttribute>(false);

        if (enumMemeberAttribute == null)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException($"Enum: '{enumType.FullName}', value: {value} does not have attribute: '{nameof(EnumMemberAttribute)}'.");
        }

        return enumMemeberAttribute.Value;
    }
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).