# Using special characters in Enum value

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I'm refactoring an ASP.NET MVC application that contains a Grid that uses remote filtering, sorting and pagination, it currently uses a string to pass the comparison operator that should be applied, I'd like to change that into an Enum:

```
Public Class MyController
    Inherits Controller
    Public Function GetOrders(filterModels As List(Of FilterModel)) As JsonResult
        'A member of FilterModel is of type EnumComparisonOperators here
        ...
    End Function
End Class

Public Enum EnumComparisonOperators
    <Description("=")>
    Equals = 0
    <Description("<>")>
    NotEquals = 1
    <Description("<=")>
    LessThanOrEquals = 2
    <Description(">")>
    GreaterThan = 3
    <Description(">=")>
    GreaterThanOrEquals = 4
End Enum
```

In the View:

```
//In the real code, my ajax call is in a callback from a third party
//component that just passes these loadOptions
var loadOptions = { 
    filterModel: { 
        operator: "=" //Replacing this string with "Equals" causes the code to work
                      //But my application logic needs a "=" sign, so I'd like to avoid 
                      //converting back and forth
    } 
};

//The exception gets thrown the server when it receives this post call
$.post("/My/GetOrders", loadOptions);
```

My problem is that this results in an exception (= is not a valid value for EnumComparisonOperators.) as the calling grid component uses the string "=" for the "equals" operation and the controller doesn't parse that automatically, so my question is:

Is there a way for me to change/decorate/configure the Enum, so that "=" is recognized by the controller as a valid value as opposed to "Equals".

So in essence I'm trying to achieve the behavior I would get if `=` were the name of my enum's value, but = is a special character so I used `Equals` and am looking for configuration that would make it behave like `=`, that means, parsing and serialization should use `=`

Comment: I cannot understand the problem :c

Comment: Edited the question but tl. dr., I want my enum value to be named `=`, not `Equals`

Comment: If the problem is that the grid component sends an `=` to this controller method, then you just need to change the comparison operator property in the `FilterModel` class to be a string instead of an enum.  Then your controller method can parse the string to find the matching enum value before processing the request.  The controller could even use reflection to find the enum value with the matching value in the `Description` attribute.

Comment: How about showing the code that throws the exception "= is not a valid value for EnumComparisonOperators"?   The [language rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/declared-element-names) will not allow the use of _**=**_ as an identifier name.

Comment: @TnTinMn The Exception is thrown when the controller is called by ajax `$.post("/My/GetOrders", loadOptions);`

Answer (score 1):

The exception "*= is not a valid value for EnumComparisonOperators*" indicates that you're passing string which doesn't recognized as proper enum value (which contains integer indexes). You can keep `<Description>` attributes for each enum members (because you can't use operator symbols as enum member like `EnumComparisonOperators.=` or `EnumComparisonOperators.<=`), but it's necessary to write your own function to set enum member value from `operator` key in JSON using reflection like example below (adapted from [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4249787)):

```
Public Function GetDescription(Of T)(ByVal value As T) As String
    Dim field As FieldInfo = value.[GetType]().GetField(value.ToString())
    Dim attributes As DescriptionAttribute() = CType(field.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(DescriptionAttribute), False), DescriptionAttribute())

    If attributes IsNot Nothing AndAlso attributes.Length > 0 Then
        Return attributes(0).Description
    Else
        Return value.ToString()
    End If
End Function

Public Function GetEnumValueFromOperator(Of T)(ByVal op As String) As T
    Dim array As Array = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(T))
    Dim list = New List(Of T)(array.Length)

    For i As Integer = 0 To array.Length - 1
        list.Add(CType(array.GetValue(i), T))
    Next

    Dim dic = list.[Select](Function(x) New With {
        .Value = v,
        .Description = GetDescription(x)
    }).ToDictionary(Function(s) s.Description, Function(s) s.Value)
    Return dic(op)
End Function
```

Afterwards, call the function above inside controller action (depending on your current implementation, these codes are subject to change):

**Model**

```
Public Class FilterModel

    Public Property operator As String

    ' other properties
End Class
```

**Controller**

```
<HttpPost()>
Public Function GetOrders(filterModels As List(Of FilterModel)) As JsonResult
    ' check against null or zero length (filterModels.Count = 0) first

    For Each fm As FilterModel In filterModels
        Dim selectedOperator = GetEnumValueFromOperator(Of EnumComparisonOperators)(fm.operator)

        Select Case selectedOperator
            Case 0 ' Equals
               ' do something
        End Select

    Next

    ' other stuff
    Return Json(...)
End Function
```

See also [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xI5WGW) for another usage example.

**Note:** Another available alternative is using `EnumMemberAttribute` like `<EnumMember(Value := "=")>` for every enum members and create a function to read that value as described in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27372816/how-to-read-the-value-for-an-enummember-attribute).

Comment: I can't call any function from the controller action because the exception is raised before the controller ever gets called, `<EnumMember(Value := "=")>` and `<JsonConverter(GetType(StringEnumConverter))>` seems to be exactly what I want, but couldn't get it to work yet. (adding them had no effect on in my case)