# C# How can I get a list of enum string in [EnumMember]?

Tags: c#, enums

I try to get the list of values in [EnumMember] but it doesn't work. It returns a list of enum names, not values in [EnumMember].

I take an example to demonstrate what I want:

CarEnum.cs

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
public enum CarEnum
{
    [EnumMember(Value = @"Rolls Royce")]
    RollsRoyce=1,

    [EnumMember(Value = @"Honda")]
    Honda = 2,

    [EnumMember(Value = @"Mercedes Benz")]
    MercedesBenz = 3,
}
```

This is the code I try to get the values:

```
var carList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CarEnum)).Cast<CarEnum>()
                            .Select(x => x.ToString())
                            .ToList();
```

The `carList` returns a list of `["RollsRoyce", "Honda", "MercedesBenz"]`.

I expect it to return `["Rolls Royce", "Honda", "Mercedes Benz"]` (the values contain space in the brand names).

Please let me know if you can help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: `enum.ToString()` returns the name of the enum member not the value of the `EnumMember` attribute. You will need to use reflection to find the value of the EnumMemberAttribute associated with each member of the enum.

Comment: Have you googled this yet? https://www.techiedelight.com/convert-enum-to-list-csharp/#:~:text=Convert%20an%20enum%20to%20a%20list%20in%20C%23,Dictionary%20of%20Enum%20members%20with%20their%20constant%20values

Comment: @Andrew yes I have. The examples use simple enum which we get the weekdate in string or int. They don't use [EnumMember] like what I do.

Comment: Hi @phuzi do you have any sample codes to demonstrate your suggestion or some posts which I can take a look? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27372816/how-to-read-the-value-for-an-enummember-attribute

Comment: @phuzi thank you very much. I have modified a bit to get a list of values instead of single value as the post. I'll add my answer soon. 
Again thank you phuzi.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @phuzi for the reference post in comment.

Based on the post, I've modified the answer as below and it works.

```
public static List<string> GetEnumMemberValues<T>() where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        var members = typeof(T)
             .GetTypeInfo()
             .DeclaredMembers;
        foreach (var member in members)
        {
            var val = member?.GetCustomAttribute<EnumMemberAttribute>(false)?.Value;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
                list.Add(val);
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Usage:

1. Put the method in a class. I put it into EnumExtension.
2. Call this method like this:

   var carList = EnumExtension.GetEnumMemberValues();
3. The `carList` returns `["Rolls Royce", "Honda", "Mercedes Benz"]` as expected.

Comment: Even though you answered the question yourself you can still accept this answer 